# how to edit string in editable datatable?

Tags: plotly-dash

I am using dash_table.DataTable() with cell value of date string.  I use editable=True so I can delete and change whole cell's value.  I am wondering if I can edit part of string value? For example, below the cell value is a date string of 2021-10-31 18:00. How can I just change month or hour data or whatever without changing whole string? Typically, we just double click the location to highlight the part which need to be changed. But this double-click doesn't work for DataTable. Thanks

```
from dash_table import DataTable

mytable=DataTable(
    id="date-table",  
    columns=columns,
    data=data,
    editable=True,
    active_cell={"row": 0, "column": 0},
    fixed_rows={"headers": True},
    sort_action="native",
    derived_virtual_data=data,
    style_table={
        "minHeight": "85vh",
        "height": "85vh",
        "overflowY": "scroll",
        "borderRadius": "0px 0px 10px 10px",
    },
    style_cell={
        "whiteSpace": "normal",
        "height": "auto",
        "font-family": "verdana",
    },
    style_header={
        "textAlign": "center",
        "fontSize": 14,
    },
    style_data={
        "fontSize": 12,
    },
    style_data_conditional=[

        {
            "if": {"column_id": 'Well'},
            "width": "30%",
            "textAlign": "center",
            "textDecoration": "underline",
            "cursor": "pointer",
        },
        
        {
            "if": {"column_id": 'Type'},
            "width": "50%",
            "textAlign": "center",
        },
        
        {
            "if": {"column_id": 'Pad'},
            "width": "20%",
            "textAlign": "center",
        },
        {"if": {"row_index": "odd"}, "backgroundColor": "#fafbfb"},
    ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is possible by double clicking THEN moving the arrow keys. Requires hitting enter to save changes. If you lose focus, they're gone.

I'm using dash 2.0.0 and dash-datatable 5.0.0.